# Tiny question about Indexed[x,n]

Tags: list-manipulation, iterators, index

Maybe I should apologize for this silly question, but the documentation for `Indexed` is very short and not explicit.

I have an equation with variables `Indexed[x,n]` and construct a sparse matrix through `CoefficientArrays`.

How can I choose all $x$ with an index value $n≥|b|$ as variables in `CoefficientArrays`?

And how can I set a rule of substitution for an indexed variable? Construction of form `Indexed[x,1]=a^2` doesn't work, so what's the correct variant?

Thank you in advance for your help

Comment: I can't quite figure out what you are asking. It would help if you could give a small snippet of code that shows the kind of thing you have and what you expect to see as output.

Comment: You could index your variables using `x[n]`; you can freely assign values to such variables.

Comment: @bills code to the first question:  `eqnsList = {5*Indexed[x, 1] - f^2 Indexed[x, -3] + 
    Sqrt[2] Indexed[x, 4] == 0, 
  1/5 Indexed[x, -4] - g Indexed[x, 2] == 0};
linsystem = CoefficientArrays[eqns, Indexed[x, 1]]`. This code is good when I get only factors of `Indexed[x, 1]`, but I don't know how to choose as variables all $x$ with an index factor $n\geq \left| 3\right|$
About the second one: if I want to substitute smth as `a^2` in all expr. for `Indexed[x,1]`, I do it like `Indexed[x,1]=a^2`, but I get only an error >Set::write: Tag Indexed in Subscript[coefA, 1] is Protected. >>

Comment: @Hedin -- you should place your code in the question itself so that others can easily find it (you can use the "edit button" to edit your question).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure I know what you are trying to accomplish, but you can do the same thing for any set of indices that you are doing for `Index[x,1]` using `Map` (shortcut /@) as follows:

```
eqnsList = {5*Indexed[x, 1] - f^2 Indexed[x, -3] + Sqrt[2] Indexed[x, 4] == 0, 
            1/5 Indexed[x, -4] - g Indexed[x, 2] == 0}; 
linsystem = CoefficientArrays[eqnsList, Indexed[x, #]] & /@ {-3, 1, 2, 4}
```

This does the same thing for indices {-3, 1, 2, 4}. Of course you can stick any set you wish in their place.

For the second question, you can use a replacement rule, for instance:

```
eqnsList /. Indexed[x, 1] -> a^2
```

replaces all occurrences of `Indexed[x, 1]` with `a^2`.

Comment: glad to help. I didn't feel easy on pure functions yet, but I'll try to fix that drawback.